# Connecting to an online database server in Javafx

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Hi guys am trying create a library management system but I want to host my database in an online server, I have gotten a free server and created my database, but now I don't really know how to connect to the online database, have search google but couldn't get any specific response..

The server am using is freemysqlhosting.com
I already have my username and password, so how do I connect to it from my application

Comment: Provide more details. Do you want to install database and access it or do you want to know how to connect to the database?

Comment: https://mkyong.com/tutorials/jdbc-tutorials/

Answer (score 1):

You may purchase or search for a free db hosting provider like

*1. [freemysqlhosting](https://www.freemysqlhosting.net/)*

Register to your preferred online hosting site then create a db and your tables.

Then you may connect to your DB from anywhere using a connection string. You can connect even from localhost.

[how to connect](https://mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/)

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class JDBCExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html#package.description
        // auto java.sql.Driver discovery -- no longer need to load a java.sql.Driver class via Class.forName

        // register JDBC driver, optional since java 1.6
        /*try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        // auto close connection
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test", "root", "password")) {

            if (conn != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected to the database!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The hosting providers will provide you with the information that you would require for connection.

```
Server: xxxx
Db_Name: xxxx
Username: xxxx
Password: xxxx
Port number: 3306
```

Once you get the details you can login to phpmyadmin online  [phpmyadmin.co](http://www.phpmyadmin.co/) and create your tables

Comment: Thanks, but am having issues connecting to the online server now, I will be glad if u give me a more detailed explanation on how to connect to the server

Comment: Did you realize the question is about Java?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my bad, i din't i was not careful to see that . but have modified . the tutorial link you have commented will be of more help  to  Tule Simon